# problem with server closing client with sockets

Tags: java, sockets, client-server

When a client disconnects, the respective instances are removed from the chats and clients lists, the error is that when I disconnect a client, the server conflicts and does not recognize that a client has disconnected.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    // TODO code application logic here
    System.out.println("Servidor Listo");
    ServerSocket server=new ServerSocket(5000);
    LinkedList<ChatData> chats=new LinkedList<>();
    LinkedList<Socket> clients=new LinkedList<>();

        while (true) 
        {            
            Socket clientsocket=server.accept();
            System.out.println("Aceptado cliente: " + clientsocket.getInetAddress().getHostName());
            ChatData chat1=new ChatData(clientsocket);
            chats.add(chat1);
            clients.add(clientsocket);

            for (ChatData chat : chats) 
            {
                chat.clients=clients;
            }
            chat1.start();
        } 
}
```

Comment: Hi, what have you tried? Please provide error logs or hints on what you see that is happening.

Comment: may 28, 2020 1:15:20 PM serverchat.ChatData run
GRAVE: null
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:209)
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:223)
 at java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedShort(DataInputStream.java:337)
 at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:589)
 at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:564)
 at serverchat.ChatData.run(ChatData.java:47)